# Complexity in time and memory for graph search algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am working on an assignment where I have to write an algorithm to detect all vertices that lie in a cycle in a graph and then calculate its complexity. I have come up with an algorithm in pseudocode. My approach is to 'delete' all vertices that have only one connecting edge until no vertexes are left that have only one connecting edge. The remaining vertices, if any, are part of a cycle.

The graph is undirected.

```c
/*
// vertices is an array containing every vertex
// e.g. vertices = [0,1,2,3,...]
*/
vertices[]

/*
// edges is a two dimensional array defining each edge
// by the two vertices it connects
// e.g. edges = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,1],...]
*/
edges[]

verticesInCycle = cycleDetection(vertices, edges, vertices)

verticesNotInCycle = vertices

foreach (verticesInCycle as vertexIC) {
    if (verticesNotInCycle.contains(vertexIC)) {
        verticesNotInCycle.remove(vertexIC);
    }
}


/*
// vertices[] = vertices to test
// edges[] = edges to test them against
// verticesLeft[] = all untested vertices that are left
*/
function cycleDetection(vertices[], edges[]), verticesLeft[]) {
    recur = false
    nextVertices[]

    foreach (vertices as vertex) {
        count = 0
        connectingEdge = null

        foreach (edges as edge) {
            if (vertex == edge[0] || vertex == edge[1]) {
                count++

                if (count > 1) {
                    break
                } else {
                    connectingEdge = edge
                }
            }
        }

        if (count == 1) {
            edges.remove(connectingEdge)
            verticesLeft.remove(vertex)

            if (connectingEdge[0] == vertex) {
                nextVertices.add(connectingEdge[1])
            } else {
                nextVertices.add(connectingEdge[0])
            }

            recur = true
        }
    }

    if (recur) {
        cycleDetection(nextVertices, edges, verticesLeft)
    } else {
        return verticesLeft
    }
}
```

### Example Run

Example graph

```
10  6
 \ / \
  1   5
  |   |
  2   4-7
  |\ /
  8 3
   \
    9
```

Initial call of `cycleDetection`

```
x   o
 \ / \
  o   o
  |   |
  o   o-x
  |\ /
  o o
   \
    x
```

First recursive call

```
    o
   / \
  o   o
  |   |
  o   o
  |\ /
  x o
```

Second recursive call

```
    o
   / \
  o   o
  |   |
  o   o
   \ /
    o
```

Done!

### Now I am calculating the complexity (time and memory)

I calculated that the complexity is approximately `O(1.4(V*E))`, where `N` is the number of vertices and `E` the number of edges.

This is based on the time (or iterations) because the maximum number of iterations (vertices and edges to check) is approximately `1.4(n*e)`, where `n` is the number of vertices and `e` the number of edges.

The worst case, which requires the most iterations, is a line of connected vertices with a cycle at one end.

```c
o
|\
| o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
|/
o
```

In this case the complexity is the number of vertices `n` times the number of edges `e` multiplied by approximately `1.4`. Initially all edges need to be iterated for every vertex but subsequently only the remaining edges need to be iterated for one vertex at a time. In the end about a fourth of `n*e` needs to be iterated through after the initial iteration of all edges for every vertex.

#### Memory usage

Memory usage is directly dependant on the amount of recursive calls, with the first call needing the most memory. Every call of `cycleDetection` uses `v + e + vL` memory, `v + e + vL` being the size of the three arrays passed as parameters.

The worst case for memory usage is a line of connected vertices with a cycle at one end (as above). In this case the amount of recursive calls required is `v - 2`, where `v` is the number of vertices given that  `v > 2`. So memory complexity is approximately `O(3)` work memory.

## The Question

**A**. I am unsure if my time complexity is formulated right? It doesn't need to be spot on but I also saw that you can leave out the multiplier and write something like **O(VxE**2)**.

**B**. I am pretty sure my memory complexity is wrong? I have read [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/memory-complexity#:%7E:text=Memory%20complexity%20is%20the%20size,only%20in%20the%20work%20tape.) and formulated my complexity accordingly based on the fact that I have three variables that I am passing to my function with every recursive call.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. `maximum number of [vertices and edges to check) is [O(n*e)]` What is the number of checks for each *vertex and edge*? Memory required would seem to depend on *parameter passing*: are *array parameters* to be copied or not? (Did you *intend* `O(3)`, constant space?)

Comment: I know the question is not about improving the algorithm but is it part of the exercise to use a recursive algorithm ? It makes the space complexity question unnecessarily complex when a while loop would do perfectly the job.

Comment: Yes, we have to use recursion. The number of check for each vertex and edge is roughly `1.4(v*e)` if that makes sense? And yes I intended constant space, didn't really know the difference.